# Show that if $ \lim_{n\to \infty} 2^{n}\left|a_{n+1} - a_n\right| = 0, $ then $a_n$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I really do not know where to start on this problem. I know the definition of convergence but I can't see where to apply it here .

Comment: What is $x$ and $\underline x$?

Comment: my apologies I edited the question

Comment: Now $x_n = 0$ for all $n$....

Comment: This is very badly written. Please edit.

Comment: Do you mean: "Let $x_n = 2^{n}\left|a_{n+1} - a_n\right|$ be a sequence such that, $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n} = 0 $ Prove that $a_n$ is a convergent sequence." ?

Comment: Readers shouldn't have to look at your title to understand your question. The whole question should be in the post. Edit.

Comment: I edited it. Tell me if my interpretation is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the condition says there exists $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ such that

$$n>N\implies 2^n|a_{n+1}-a_n|<1\implies |a_{n+1}-a_n|<\frac1{2^n}$$

So let us take $\;n>N\;,\;\;p\in\Bbb N\;$ , and:$${}$$

$$|a_{n+p}-a_n|=|a_{n+p}-a_{n+p-1}+a_{n+p-1}-a_{n+p-2}+\ldots+ a_{n+1}-a_n|\le$$

$$\le|a_{n+p}-a_{n+p-1}|+|a_{n+p-1}-a_{n+p-2}|+\ldots +|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le$$

$$\;\le\frac1{2^{n+p-1}}+\frac1{2^{n+p-2}}+\ldots+\frac1{2^n}=\frac1{2^n}\frac{1-\frac1{2^{p-1}}}{1-\frac12}=\frac1{2^n}\left(2-\frac1{2^{p-2}}\right)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

and then the sequence is Cauchy and thus it converges.